# Delete Array Of Filenames Inside A Foreach Loop Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, foreach

I am creating a 'delete account' function for users of a site if they want to delete all of their details.

Deleting the relevant records from the database has been pretty straight forward. However, I want to deleted the images they have saved in the site's images folder.

Below is the code I'm trying, a part of which is based on @kmoser's suggestion.

```
// $db_image_id, $db_image_ext, $db_image_filename are fetched in a previous code block for when images are outputted on the page.

if(isset($_POST['delete-account'])) {

    $loggedInUser = $_SESSION['logged_in'];
    $imagesLibrary = 'images-lib/';
    $imagesDownload = 'images-download/';

    try {

    $s = $connection->prepare("SELECT filename FROM `imageposts` WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $s->bindParam(':user_id', $loggedInUser);
    $s->execute();

    // -- DELETE THE USER'S IMAGE FILES FROM 'IMAGES-LIB' FOLDER
    while ($row = $s->fetch()) { 
        if (isset($pattern)) {
            $pattern = $imagesLibrary . $row['filename'] . '-{500,750,1000,1500}' . '.' . $row['file_extension'];
            foreach (glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE) as $filenames) {
                unlink($filenames);
            }
        }
    }
                        
    header("Location: index.php");

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The key piece of the above code is this snippet below:

```
// -- DELETE IMAGE FILES FROM 'IMAGES-LIB' FOLDER
while ($row = $s->fetch()) { 
    if (isset($pattern)) {
        $pattern = $imagesLibrary . $row['filename'] . '-{500,750,1000,1500}' . '.' . $row['file_extension'];
        foreach (glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE) as $filenames) {
            unlink($filenames);
        }
    }
}
```

I was initially getting an error `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file_extension in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site/profile-edit.php` in relation to the 3rd line of PHP code above that declares the `$pattern` variable. I've managed to fix this by wrapping the code in the `if(isset($pattern))` if statement that is now present. I don't get any error logs now, but the files are not being deleted out of the 'images-lib' directory.

A typical filename example is `6146972e2dc73_1632016174-500.jpeg`

Here is an example of how the files look in the database:

[image: image file names in MySQL database]

When outputted onto a page in an `<img>` tag, the size e.g. `-500` part of the filename is concatenated on with a string inside the `src` attribute.

`src="<?php echo '/images-lib/' . $db_image_filename . '-500' . '.' . $db_image_ext; ?>"`

Any help or assistance on how to delete images specific to a user from the images directory would be wonderful.

Comment: For the filenames stored in the `imageposts` table, are there multiple sizes of each stored in the filesystem, or just one?

Comment: @kmoser just one per image in the database table. When outputted on to a page in an img tag the src attribute has the size concatenated on as a string value.

Comment: `if (isset($pattern))` is not the right way to fix the "Undefined index: file_extension" error. You need to change `SELECT filename FROM \`imageposts\`` to `SELECT filename, file_extension FROM \`imageposts\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to store the filenames and extensions in separate arrays, or even in an array at all. Just fetch every image filename and extension in a loop, assemble it into a pattern (e.g. `images/6146972e2dc73_1632016174-{500,750,1000,1500}.jpeg`, then `glob()` the pattern to find each matching file and unlink it:

```
while ($row = $s->fetch()) { 
    $pattern = $imagesLibrary . $row['filename'] . '-{500,750,1000,1500}.' . $row['file_extension'];
    foreach (glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
        unlink($filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Images in the image directory do all have the size as part of the file name though (4 sizes in total). The example filename I gave is for the 500px size. The filenames are generated when the images are uploaded and placed in the directory. This resizing and renaming of the uploaded images is done with the php Imagick image library.

Comment: @paulo_cam Without specific examples of filenames and extensions in the DB, and specific examples of the matching files in the filesystem, it's difficult to understand what you're trying to say. However, I've updated my answer so hopefully it works now.

Comment: @paulo_cam Please edit your question to show the exact PHP code being executed, and indicate which line is causing the error.

Comment: OK I've done that. I've included the code from your answer which seems to be getting me further even though it isn't working yet, and have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks. That works a treat now.